# What should be the Correct implementation for product Selection logic using MVVM SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, mvvm

I have recently started with SwiftUI-MVVM and am not sure about the way am doing things in MVVM. Am displaying list of products via this property in ViewModel `@Published var list: [Product]` and one product can be select at one time only so i created `@Published` property in ViewModel as `@Published var selectedProduct: Product`. Now am passing the data in ProductRow view as

```
ForEach(viewModel.list) product in {    
     ProductRow(product, selectedProduct: $viewModel.selectedProduct)
     .tapGesture {
         viewModel.selectedProduct = product
     }
}
```

Inside `ProductRow` view am changing the color of selected product.

So i want to know am i on right path of using MVVM to achieve this functionality or there are other best ways to achieve these kind of logic in MVVM.

I want to keep all the logic inside ViewModel so i didn't created any `@State` property for selectedProduct.

Comment: It looks like you are on the right way if you are using MVVM but this is not a good question for stackoverflow since it's a bit vague and opinionated. Two things I would comment on, why do you need to pass the selected product to each row and shouldn't selectedProduct be declared as optional?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson I know this is not right question for stackoverflow but i have gone through from lot of sample projects and documentation but i was confused related to the implementation. Am passing selectedProduct into each row so that i can compare row product with selectedproduct so i can change the color of that specific row only.

Comment: @SumitJangra Well, are you facing a problem here? Why do you think this might not be the "best way"? Joakim is right. Unless you have a default product, selectedProduct should be optional. ProductRow shouldn't need to know about selectedProduct. You should be ideally checking the selectedProduct and just pass the foregroundColor to the ProductRow (since you have published the selectedProduct, the view is going to be redrawn anyways) or perhaps create a viewmodifier

Comment: @Aswath I agree selectedProduct should be optional. I just give the example of changing the color, what if i have to perform other operations as well based upon selected product. What i think is product row should only contain one model which am passing inside ForEach instead of passing selectedProduct binding inside product row. So i want to know about my approach is right or not ?

Comment: @Aswath You mentioned i can achieve this with viewmodifier, can you help me with some example code.

Comment: you don't need MVVM in SwiftUI. In SwiftUI the View struct holds the view data, i.e. it is the view model already. It looks like your products is model data anyway so you just need one object to load and save it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible improvement. It does not use view modifiers since I'm doing only a background color change

```
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ProductPage: View {
    class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
        var products: [Product] = [Product(name: "Milk"), Product(name: "Candy"), Product(name: "Carrot")]
        @Published var selectedProduct: Product?
    }
    
    @StateObject var viewModel: ViewModel = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.products) { product in
                ProductRow(product: product, foregroundColor: getForegroundColor(for: product))
                    .onTapGesture {
                        viewModel.selectedProduct = product
                    }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func getForegroundColor(for product: Product) -> Color {
        (product == viewModel.selectedProduct) ? .red : .black
    }
}
            
struct Product: Identifiable, Equatable {
    var name: String
    var id: String { name }
}

struct ProductRow: View {
    var product: Product
    var foregroundColor: Color
    var body: some View {
        Text(product.name)
            .foregroundColor(foregroundColor)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(
    ProductPage()
)
```